# How do I install QuickSubmit plugin to OJS 3.2.1?

Tags: plugins, ojs

When I go to Plugin Gallery and click on "install quicksubmit plugin", I get a message saying that `The loaded plugin file does not contain a folder that matches the plugin name`. Where do I save this folder?

I found an explanation on PKP Help that said:

> Most plugins should come with a readme file of some sort, and should also list which versions of OJS they are compatible with. To install a plugin, you should simply need to copy the files to the correct plugins subdirectory in your OJS installation. For example, if the plugin you want to install is considered a 'generic' plugin, copy the plugin folder to `plugins/generic/`; if it is classed as an import plugin, it should go into `plugins/importexport`; and so on.

But where can I find this `plugins/generic/` or `plugins/importexport` folders?

Answer (score 1):

This error is usually when you trying to direct install latest plugin into previous version of ojs please follow bellow steps to easily install this plugin.

1. Download the exact released version for your ojs from

   https://github.com/pkp/quickSubmit .

   Example if you are running ojs 3.2.0 then download the relevant zip
2. upload this zip file and extract to your ojs/plugins/importexport directory
3. after extraction login to dashboard and check in tool->import/export plugin will be installed

Answer (score 0):

The way to manually install any plugin is as follows:

1. Download the version of the plugin that is appropriate for your OJS installation from github and unpack it.
2. Check the `version.xml` file and see what the `<type> </type>` tag contains. It will be something like `plugins.[plugin-type]`, which tells you what folder the plugin should go.
3. Go to `ojs/plugins/plugin-type` (depending on what you saw in the previous step) and copy the plugin folder that you unpacked in step 1.
4. In the dashboard panel, go to `Settings->Website->Plugins` or `Administration->Site Settings->Plugins` (depending on whether the plugin is site-wide or only for a specific journal in multi-journal installations), find the plugin in the list and click the check box to enable the plugin.